# Haskell Defining a List and List Comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

Good morning!

I am trying to define a list that takes in all possible Address types, which I have previously defined, and use list comprehension to do so.

Here's what I've got for earlier definitions that will likely be helpful for you to know:

```
data Row = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J deriving (Enum, Ord, Show, Bounded, Eq, Read)
data Column = One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten  deriving (Enum, Ord, Show, Bounded, Eq, Read)
data Address = Address Row Column deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
data Cell = Cell Address Bool deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

I'm not sure if I need to be using Cell in this solution, but perhaps.

This is my current solution, and I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions on improving it, or perhaps it's just completely wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated!

```
allAddressesA = [ x * y | x <- [Row] y <- [Column]]
```

And just for reference, here's a formal written requirement:

> Define allAddressesA as the list of all possible board Addresses. Use
>   a list comprehension that uses ranges of your Row and Column types.

Thank you! I'll be closely monitoring this so feel free to ask anything that you need clarified to help. I appreciate you taking the time to read this and potentially offer advice :)

Comment: Surely you can tell whether it's completely wrong or not by simply trying it and seeing if it works?

Comment: Try to compile your code, then read the error messages carefully.

Comment: Verifying whether your list of addresses compiles and produces the right answer should be entirely self-contained and not need the rest of the code to test. From what I can see your code has multiple type and even *syntax* errors, so it's clear you've not tried anything yourself.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to be your compiler. Compile the code, read the errors, and fix any you can. If you have specific questions, then come ask for help.

Comment: @Joodoo there is **no way** the code you showed in your post compiled .

Comment: @Joodoo: Really, it compiled despite at least one syntax error, probably two names not in scope, and what would be a type error if the other problems were fixed? And yes, it is entirely possible to test, even if you don't know, and didn't try to figure out, how to do so.

Comment: @C.A.McCann My apologies for being a tool, I have been shown the error of my ways, both in Haskell and at talking on the internet. I responded to you very poorly and I'm sorry.

Comment: @Joodoo: Fortunately, other people were far more patient and helpful than I. My apologies as well for being so brusque. That said, as nice as dblhelix's answer is, there is material for learning Haskell that's at least as good already available on the internet, and your questions will likely be better received if you consult those first before asking here. If this is coursework of some sort, are you using a textbook, and if so what is it?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Pragmatics-Third-Michael/dp/0123745144   That's our textbook, but there's not much good stuff for Haskell in there. The official response from the instructor was "make friends with Google"

Comment: It's also one of those "the curriculum wants you to learn it, but, eh" type of things :)

Comment: @Joodoo: Oh, *good grief.* In that case: [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) if you like silly illustrations, [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) if you don't, and/or [The Gentle Introduction](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/) which is no-nonsense and not actually very gentle. All three are available for free online, and at least the first two can be bought in dead tree format. LYAH seems to be most popular these days, and RWH may be slightly dated in some of its examples.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29376/discussion-between-joodoo-and-c-a-mccann)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You write:

> This is my current solution, and I'm wondering if anyone has
>   suggestions on improving it, or perhaps it's just completely wrong.

Whether it is completely wrong can be easily tested of course. Just type it in and ask your compiler:

```
allAddressesA = [ x * y | x <- [Row] y <- [Column]]
```

Mine says:

```
parse error on input `<-'
```

I guess that qualifies as wrong.

So, let us first fix the syntax. The possibly multiple clauses in the second part of a list comprehension (the part after the `|`, that is) are to be separated by commas. Doing so gives:

```
allAddressesA = [ x * y | x <- [Row], y <- [Column]]
```

What does the compiler think of that?

```
Not in scope: data constructor `Row'
Not in scope: data constructor `Column'
```

Indeed, `Row` and `Column` are type constructors rather than data constructors. That means that you can use them to build type expressions, but not to build "ordinary" value expressions.

Clearly, we are on the wrong path. So let us take a few steps back.

Both your `Row` type and your `Column` type are in the type classes `Enum` and `Bounded`. Hence, we can easily produce lists with all row and column designators, respectively:

```
allRows    = [minBound :: Row    .. maxBound]
allColumns = [minBound :: Column .. maxBound]
```

(Using `minBound` and `maxBound` makes your code somewhat more robust than immediately using `A` and `J`, and `One` and `Ten`, respectively, in the sense that adding constructors to `Row` and `Column` does not require you to change the definitions of `allRows` and `allColumns`.)

In an interactive environment we can easily evaluate these lists. Indeed, printing `allRows` gives:

```
> allRows
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J]
```

and for `allColumns` we get

```
> allColumns
[One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten]
```

Now, as an address consists of a row and a column designator, generating all possible addresses simply reduces to taking the cross product of all rows and all columns. With the previous definitions for `allRows` and `allColumns` in place, we can easily write such a cross product as a list comprehension:

```
allAddresses = [Address row column | row <- allRows, column <- allColumns]
```

As you have 10 row designators and 10 column designators, you end up with a list of 10 x 10 = 100 addresses:

```
> length allAddresses
100
```

For amusement's sake, let us print the first 15:

```
> take 15 allAddresses
[Address A One,Address A Two,Address A Three,Address A Four,Address A Five,
Address A Six,Address A Seven,Address A Eight,Address A Nine,Address A Ten,
Address B One,Address B Two,Address B Three,Address B Four,Address B Five]
```

Comment: You should write a book. Holy answer, Batman. Gonna bookmark this one for later reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the skeleton for your code:

```
allAddressesA = [ Address {- ... -} | x <- [A .. J], y <- [ {- ... -} ]]
```

replace each `{- ... -}` with the correct code.

```
data Address = Address Row Column
```

means that you get to create compound data of type `Address`, by using a constructor function named `Address`, which expects two arguments: first of type `Row`, and second of type `Column`. In specifying ranges, we show data elements, not types or course: we write `[1 .. 10]`, not `[Int]`.

Comment: Wow, yeah I didn't have that close at all. What is the {- -} business? I don't see that in my textbook.

Comment: that's the multi-line comments

Comment: OH oh, I see what you did there. Okay, I thought that was some odd syntax that I hadn't seen before. Gracias amigo

Comment: *Noob on board :) I thought you had to comment stuff with -- each time

Comment: @Joodoo you should really study the basics. So have you succeeded in filling out the blanks?

Comment: Yeah now that I see your reasoning I have had success. So I ended up doing [One, Two, Three (blah blah)] for the last blank, and the Address part I'm still chewing on, but since `[x * y | x <- [1, 2, 3], y <- [1, 2, 3]]` would give me the multiplication table, I assume I need two arguments in there. So couldn't I just do x * y in there as well to get, for example, A One, A Two, etc?

Comment: Note I wrote `Address {- ... -} ` there, not `x * y`. What goes after `Address` function name? Which arguments?

Comment: A Row and a Column. Isn't that what I'm feeding it with the x list and y list?  `allAddressesA = [ Address x * Address y | x <- [A .. J], y <- [One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten]]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29374/discussion-between-will-ness-and-joodoo)